# How can I configure an IP address for beaglebone?

Tags: beagleboneblack, buildroot

I followed the tutorial of free-electrons to configure ip address using rootfs overlay but when I run make I got this error:

```
    /sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't open configuration file /home/slim/Bureau/projet_stage/buildroot/output/target/etc/ld.so.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

( \
        echo "NAME=Buildroot"; \
        echo "VERSION=2015.05"; \
        echo "ID=buildroot"; \
        echo "VERSION_ID=2015.05"; \
        echo "PRETTY_NAME=\"Buildroot 2015.05\"" \
    ) >  /home/slim/Bureau/projet_stage/buildroot/output/target/etc/os-release

    rsync: change_dir "/home/slim/Bureau/projet_stage/buildroot//board/felabs/beagleboneblack/rootfs-overlay" failed: No such file or directory (2)
    rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1070) [sender=3.0.9]
    make: *** [target-finalize] Error 23
```

How can I configure the IP address to be static.

Comment: Well, do you have a `rootfs-overlay` file at `/home/user/Desktop/Buildroot/board/felabs/`?
If you do, could you show us exactly what you have done? Configurations, changes etc?

Comment: On the folder board I don't have felabs folder so I create a folder which it names is felabs then I created on it a folder rootfs-overlay.

Comment: How does your `/home/user/Desktop/Buildroot/board/felabs/rootfs-overlay` directory look like? (e.g. `ls -R`). How does your config look like? Do you get any more errors?

Comment: @Anders:I edited the question

Comment: .config:http://pastebin.com/MhtrBCzA

Comment: well, previously you stated that you create `rootfs-overlay` as a directory under `board/felabs`. However, you're new error message (and config) looks under `board/felabs/beagleboneblack/rootfs-overlay`. Could you double-check that? The error message is pretty clear in that rsync can't change to that directory, thus I think you need to look one more time at all paths. Try to run `cd /home/slim/Bureau/projet_stage/buildroot//board/felabs/beagleboneblack/rootfs-overlay` to see if you yourself are able to change to that directory.

Comment: I tried cd /home/slim/Bureau/projet_stage/buildroot//board/felabs/beagleboneblack/rootfs-ov‌​erlay : no such file or directory

Comment: Well, that's your issue then.

Comment: I don't understand why I got double "/" on this path "/home/slim/Bureau/projet_stage/buildroot//board/felabs/beagleboneblack/rootfs-ov‌​erlay"??

Comment: Double `/` is usually not a problem (other than cosmetic). Try to remove components from the path one-by-by, to find where the error is.